# Communicating variables between classes

Tags: php, class, oop

What is the best way to communicate variables between classes with these conditions:

1. No inheritance
2. No static or abstract functions
3. Two classes in different PHP files

So

Class.php

```
Class 1{
public $x 
    function setx(){
       $this-> x = 20
    }
}
```

Class2.php

```
Class_2{

 #get value of $x in this class

}
```

Comment: is it a static variable (never changes value) ?

Comment: extend it ..simple :)

Comment: @CodingAnt "*1. No inheritance*"

Comment: @CodingAnt besides the requirement -- would you just extend **any** class to which you need access?

Comment: Nope ! ok I am wrong !

Comment: Well your problem is pretty unclear. You should notice, that you can have many instances of `class 1` and if you want to get value you should pick it from one instance and somehow  choose it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. classes cannot communicate without static methods, *instances* can.
2. getters and setters are the antithesis of OOP, do you have a not-so-synthetic scenario in mind?
3. if instances of class `X` can do useful work, and instances of class `Y` want to drive them, they should just do so.

notice no getters or setters, and `Shelf->stuff` is testable without a `Book` instance.

```
class Shelf
{
  function stuff($thickness)
  {
    if ($this->spaceLeft < $thickness)
      throw new ShelfOverflow;
    $this->spaceLeft -= $thickness;
  }
}
class Book
{
  function shelve(Shelf $s)
  {
    $s->stuff($this->thickness);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a get method in your class1 and call it in class2:

Class.php

```
Class 1{
    public $x 
    function setx(){
       $this-> x = 20
    }

    function getx() {
        return $this->x;
    }
}
```

Class2.php

```
Class_2{

    function someMethod() {
        Class_1 c = new Class_1();
        c.getx();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

include class2 and use extension

```
class Class2 extends Class1 {
   public function z(){
    print $x;
   }
}
```